# In ReactJS, using Reactstrap, I want my alert to stay at the same place on the screen it starts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

Here is my alert:

```
<MobileView>
  <UncontrolledAlert color="danger" fade={false}>
    <h4>
      This page is not optimized for mobile.
      <br/>
      Please view on a desktop device.
    </h4>
  </UncontrolledAlert>
</MobileView>
```

but when the user scrolls, the alert moves. I want it to stay put.

Here's the best documentation on `alert` I could find https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/Alert.js

Answer (score 1):

I would just do `<Alert style={{position: 'fixed'}}/>`

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/boe16gLr/

Comment: can I do this with an UncontrolledAlert? Unless you can also tell me how to make a regular alert dismissable; just putting what you have makes it not appear

Comment: It works with UncontrolledAlert: https://jsfiddle.net/1wsm0bxp/.  If you want good help you should make an example we can see - I don't know what the rest of your code is like.  Could be that you have other items that appear on top of the Alert hiding it, but since we can't see what you have, we don't know.  Position fixed is how you make it not move.

Comment: on mine, the alert isn't even there anymore

Comment: what could it be? @dave

Comment: chances are it is in the DOM, but showing up somewhere unexpected.  Put it back the way it was, open it up in chrome dev tools, add the `position: fixed` from there, and see what happens to the element.  Or make a jsfiddle that shows the problem and I'll help you out.